# Some lowercase letters are very small in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

I think I've screwed something up in Photoshop. While using Myriad Pro, some lowercase letters appear very small. See screenshot:

[image]

I feel like there's a simple fix to this, but my Google searches have proven unsuccessful. I have found that if I highlight a letter, a glyphs pop-up appears, showing 3 different options for that letter. I'm able to revert it back to the correct form, but I want to set the default back to the way it was. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you accidentally enabled the OpenType feature "Ordinals".

[image: The OpenType feature "ordinals" selected in Photoshop CC2017]

Why are only the characters 'o' and 'a' superscripted, and not the entire text?

The function of *ordinals* is different from *superscript*:

> *Function:* Replaces default alphabetic glyphs with the corresponding ordinal forms for use after figures. One exception to the follows-a-figure rule is the numero character (U+2116), which is actually a ligature substitution, but is best accessed through this feature.
>   *Example:* The user applies this feature to turn 2.o into 2.º (abbreviation for secundo).
>   (Microsoft OpenType specification, https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/features_ko.htm#ordn)

Some fonts contain properly drawn superscript characters to support proper ordinals for the most frequent English ordinal indicators "st", "nd" and so on, to enable "1<sup>st</sup>", "2<sup>nd</sup>" – more rare fonts do not assume English only and contain the entire lowercase alphabet.

Minion Pro contains <sup>è</sup> so one can typeset "2<sup>ième</sup>" with confidence. (The accented character may be meant for another language and number. If you look this up you may find "the only correct abbreviation for *deuxième* is 2<sup>e</sup>".)

Most font designers don't go that far. But as the specific *characters* 'ª' (feminine ordinal indicator, Unicode U+00AA) and 'º' (masculine ordinal indicator, Unicode U+00BA) are part of the recommended basic supported character set "Latin-1", they usually appear in fonts anyway. From that, it's a small step to add the *feature* 'ordinals', because its most basic form is to only swap 'a' for 'ª' and 'o' for 'º'.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have superscript on. Check your character settings in the character window.

[image]